# Scatter points assigned colour from CSV file

Tags: colors, integer, scatter-plot

I am importing CSV data in the format x,y,z,p to plot a trisurface which has the scatter plots displayed on top.

The trisurface script works (ax.plot_trisurf), however, I would like to colour the scatter points (ax.scatter) according to either the 1 or -1 assigned in the fourth column of the CSV file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69bvm.png)
The x,y,z data is complicated and can't be coloured, hence trying to assign it as simply as possible in the fourth column.

I have attached a basic image, essentially I just want to be able to have a selection of the red dots a different colour without affecting the trisurface they are on.

Any comments or suggestions are be very welcome!

My most recent error is:

```
ax.scatter(X, Y, np.log10(Z), c= (not p <= (0)({True: 'g', False: 'r'})), marker='o')
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
enter code here

from typing import Any

import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
import bbox
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

# Import CSV data
from numpy import ndarray

csvFileName = sys.argv[0]
csvData = []
with open('ParvaluesMESS.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
 csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
 for csvRow in csvReader:
     csvData.append(csvRow)

csvData = np.array(csvData)
csvData = csvData.astype(float)

X, Y, Z, p = csvData[:,0], csvData[:,1], csvData[:,2], csvData[:,3]

# Plot management: note Z is logged
# Change vmin and vmax values for colorbar range if needed
# Alpha value is transparency
# 111 means 1x1 grid, first subplot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

cb = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, np.log10(Z), cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75)
#cb = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, np.log10(Z), cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75, vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax.scatter(X, Y, np.log10(Z), col==(p > 0({True: 'g', False: 'r'})), marker='o')

#ax.zaxis._set_scale('log')

def log_tick_formatter(val, pos=None):
 """Reformat log ticks for display"""
 return f"$10^{{{int(val)}}}$"

# Set Z axis to log
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(log_tick_formatter))
# ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))


def ticklabels(ticks):
 ticks_labels = []
 for i in ticks:
     ticks_labels.append(f'2^{np.log2(i)}')
 return ticks_labels


fig.colorbar(cb, shrink=0.5)

ax.set_title("First-year sea ice PAR")
ax.set_xlabel("Ice Thickness m")
ax.set_ylabel("Snow thickness m")
ax.set_zlabel("µmol $^{m-2}$ $^{s-1}$")
ax.view_init(azim=70, elev=30)
ax.set_xlim3d(20, 350)

image_format = 'png' # e.g .png, .svg, etc.
image_name = 'test.eps'

plt.show()
fig.savefig(image_name, format=image_format, dpi=1200)
```

Answer (score 0):

it was resolved by rearranging into arrays:

```
from typing import Any
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from numpy import ndarray

data=pd.read_csv('ParvaluesMESS.csv',header=None,sep=',',names=. 
['Ice','Snow','umol','P'])

x=data[['Ice']].to_numpy()
y=data[['Snow']].to_numpy()
z=data[['umol']].to_numpy()
p=data[['P']].to_numpy()

x=(x.astype(float)).flatten()
y=(y.astype(float)).flatten()
z=(z.astype(float)).flatten()
p=(p.astype(float)).flatten()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cb = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, np.log10(z), cmap='coolwarm', alpha=0.75)
ax.scatter(x, y, np.log10(z),c=p,cmap='RdYlGn')

#your formats
def log_tick_formatter(val, pos=None):
"""Reformat log ticks for display"""
return f"$10^{{{int(val)}}}$"


# Set Z axis to log
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(log_tick_formatter))


# ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(integer=True))


def ticklabels(ticks):
ticks_labels = []
for i in ticks:
    ticks_labels.append(f'2^{np.log2(i)}')
return ticks_labels


fig.colorbar(cb, shrink=0.5)

ax.set_title("First-year sea ice PAR")
ax.set_xlabel("Ice Thickness m")
ax.set_ylabel("Snow thickness m")
ax.set_zlabel("Âµmol $^{m-2}$ $^{s-1}$")
ax.view_init(azim=70, elev=30)
ax.set_xlim3d(20, 350)

image_name = 'BenImag'
image_format = 'png'  # e.g .png, .svg, etc.

plt.show()
fig.savefig(image_name, format=image_format, dpi=1200)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).